# How to know if a relation has been updated on a given model in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently working on a Laravel application which is using Model events to perform data validation / synchronization in the database.

I've a table which contains important data. This table is updated on different Model updates. I use model events to handle that. It works on Model properties example :

```
<?php
Product::saved(function (Product $p) {
    $dirty = collect($p->getDirty());
    if ($dirty->has('ugr') || $dirty->has('ra')) {
        //Do some stuff here
    }
});
```

With that kind of logic I can restrict my "stuff" execution on specific model property update.

How can I make that kind of check on `Product` relations ?

I've a ManyToMany relationships accessible through the `applications` methods on `Product`, how can I know if the linked application list has changed since model loading ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have'nt found a way to do this with Laravel directly. I've built a solution using Application events and Relation inheritance.

I've added a `trait` named `App\Database\Eloquent\FollowUpdatedRelations` which have the goal to notify relation updates :

```
<?php

namespace App\Database\Eloquent;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use App\Library\Decorator;
use App\Events\RelationUpdated;

trait FollowUpdatedRelations
{
    /**
     * The default error bag.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $updatedRelations = [];

    /**
     * Check if the belongs to many relation has been updated
     * @param  BelongsToMany $relation
     * @param  array         $syncResult Result of the `sync` method call
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function hasBeenUpdated(BelongsToMany $relation, array $syncResult)
    {
        if (isset($syncResult['attached']) && count($syncResult['attached']) > 0) {
            $this->updatedRelations[$relation->getRelationName()] = true;
            event(new RelationUpdated($relation));
        } elseif (isset($syncResult['detached']) && count($syncResult['detached']) > 0) {
            $this->updatedRelations[$relation->getRelationName()] = true;
            event(new RelationUpdated($relation));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Decorate a BelongsToMany to listen to relation update
     * @param  BelongsToMany $relation
     * @return Decorator
     */
    protected function decorateBelongsToMany(BelongsToMany $relation)
    {
        $decorator = new Decorator($relation);
        $decorator->decorate('sync', function ($decorated, $arguments) {
            $updates = call_user_func_array([$decorated, 'sync'], $arguments);
            $this->hasBeenUpdated($decorated, $updates);
            return $updates;
        });

        return $decorator;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the list of dirty relations
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDirtyRelations()
    {
        return $this->updatedRelations;
    }
}
```

I've used this trait in the Model on which I need to follow relation updates and I've updated the relation definition :

```
<?php

...

class Product extends Model
{
    use FollowUpdatedRelations;

    ....


    /**
     * Defines relationship with App\Applications model
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function applications()
    {
        return $this->decorateBelongsToMany(
            $this->belongsToMany('App\Application', 'product_application')
        );
    }
}
```

The `App\Library\Decorator` class wrap an object and add the ability to override methods :

```
<?php

namespace App\Library;

use Closure;

class Decorator
{
    /**
     * Decorated instance
     * @var mixed
     */
    private $decorated;

    private $methods = [];

    /**
     * Decorate given instance
     * @param mixed $toDecorate
     */
    public function __construct($toDecorate)
    {
        $this->decorated = $toDecorate;
    }

    /**
     * Decorate a method
     * @param string  $name
     * @param Closure $callback Method to run instead of decorated one
     */
    public function decorate($name, Closure $callback)
    {
        $this->methods[$name] = $callback;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Call a method on decorated instance
     * @param  string $name
     * @param  array  $arguments
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        if (isset($this->methods[$name])) {
            return call_user_func_array($this->methods[$name], [$this->decorated, $arguments]);
        }

        return call_user_func_array([$this->decorated, $name], $arguments);
    }
}
```

With that object I can create my custom `sync` method on the `BelongsToMany` Laravel relation. I use the sync method to follow updates because it returns the list of attached, detached and updated model in the pivot table.

I just need to count if there are attached or detached models and dispatched the corresponding event. My event is `App\Events\RelationUpdated` and contains the updated relation as property.

Then I can add an event listener in the `EventServiceProvider` like that :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use App\Events\RelationUpdated;
use App\Product;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any other events for your application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
    {
        parent::boot($events);

        ...

        //When a listened relation is updated, we perform a Model save
        $events->listen(RelationUpdated::class, function ($event) {
            //Here I do my stuff
        });
    }
}
```

I can put all the stuff that must be executed when a relation is updated. Seems a bit complicated but I think that relying on something like that is lighter than adding logic on each model construction.

Hope this help !

Comment: This solution is not working with Laravel 6

Answer (score 2):

There is no ready made approach to do this. Actually, you want to notify the parent object whenever the child object is updated. In other words, you want to trigger the saved handler on Product if any related Application is updated.

If my understanding is right then, you need to register the handler through the Product model because, if you want to notify only the related model on it's related child model update then you can simply use the `protected $touches` property in the child model so parent model will always be updated if any child model is changed.

Since, you want to track the change only the related models that are loaded (eagerly) when the main was loaded, so you need to register the saved handler on related models through the parent/main model itself. If I'm still on the right track then, you may try something like this:

```
$product = Product::with('applications')->findOrFail($id);

// Check if there are any Application loaded (eagerly) with Product
if($product->relationLoaded('applications')) {

    // Loop through each Application instance loaded with Product
    $product->applications->each(function($application) use($product) {

        // Register the saved event handler on each Application instance
        $application->saved(function($app) use($product)  {

            // If nothing has been changed do nothing
            if(!count($dirty = $app->getDirty())) return true;

            // Check if prop_1 or prop_2 has been changed in $app
            $props = ['prop_1', 'prop_2']; // You may add more props

            $keys = array_intersect_key($props, array_keys($dirty));

            if(count($keys)) {
                // Do some stuff here
                // You can do something with $product as well
                // If you have saved handler on Product then just try
                // $product->touch(); // it'll trigger that handler on Product
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Hope, you want something like I described above. Btw, this is just an idea and you may use separate class/method to register event handler on child models to keep the code clean.

Comment: Your solution seems working but it's a bit complicated for me. Register on each loaded application, related to the product, the saved handler... Also, I use a pivot table so the related model is not a real Model it's a Pivot one...
I've built a solution yesterday evening using application events and event Listeners. I'll submit it as answer today.

Comment: Sure,  submit your solution, so it'll be helpful for future visitors  and me as well,  to understand it.

Comment: I've added my solution, can you take a look ?